# Bash - read case with multiple selections

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I'm using the following code in a script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p "Do your Choice: [1] [2] [3] [4] [E]xit: " choice
    case "$choice" in
        [1]* ) echo -e "$choice\n"; break;;
        [2]* ) echo -e "$choice\n"; break;;
        [3]* ) echo -e "$choice\n"; break;;
        [4]* ) echo -e "$choice\n"; break;;
        [Ee]* ) echo "exited by user"; exit;;
        * ) echo "Are you kidding me???";;
    esac
done
```

My question is, how can I get the script to accept multiple Choices.
so input like: `1,4,` would run case `[1]` and `[4]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set IFS to include commas:

```
IFS=', '
```

Then process the choices in a loop (note the `-a` flag for `read` so the input is treated as an array):

```
while true; do
    read -p "Do your Choice: [1] [2] [3] [4] [E]xit: " -a array
    for choice in "${array[@]}"; do
        case "$choice" in
            [1]* ) echo -e "$choice\n";;
            [2]* ) echo -e "$choice\n";;
            [3]* ) echo -e "$choice\n";;
            [4]* ) echo -e "$choice\n";;
            [Ee]* ) echo "exited by user"; exit;;
            * ) echo "Are you kidding me???";;
        esac
    done
done
```

Comment: I guess OP's code uses the `break` to exit from the `while` loop.