# Bash case arguments as user input

Tags: bash

In a bash script

Any idea how to pass an argument with `case`, e.g.

```
...
case $var in
a) <some_function> $(read -p "user input:")
b) ...
c) ...
```

Such that the function turns that user input into a variable and uses its

Note: Wording is probably clumsy and I know you can do this from the beginning of your shell script. What I'm trying to get at is essentially 'nested scripts'; features within the larger script that are modular and re-usable

Thanks

Comment: Put that `read` inside the function?

Comment: Why not `some_function "$(IFS= read -r -p 'user input: ' input; printf '%s' "$input")"` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372001/bash-read-case-with-multiple-selections, https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/, ...  You can put any code you want inside a case statement, including reads.

Answer (score 0):

`read` by default assigns the `REPLY` variable

```
...
case "$var" in
a) read -p 'user input:'; <some_function> "$REPLY";;
b) ...
c) ...
```